# Core Data in background: Using separate context and notifications, but not updating DB with new values

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency

Overview: I have a refresh process that runs in the background (just using performInBackground is all) and part of that has db updates so I have a separate MOC for the background thread. I then use the didSave notification to merge in the changes, but I'm not see those updates in the DB/my UI. I've logged the object itself before and after the save and I can see the attribute is changed, but in the method called by notification, I log the objects in the context received and it doesnt have updated value. I know some other things are probably ugly, but just trying to figure out this core data piece. I previously had just one MOC and things worked (non core data should be fine), but I've rearchitected things to be in background now and wanted to use guidance of a separate MOC.

Create context, setup notification, set attribute and save. Post save, the value is 0

```
// this creates context with same PSC as main MOC
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MyAppDelegate application] temporaryContext];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
                                         selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:context];                  
NSLog(@"value is %d", [[myObject email] boolValue]); //value is 1
[myObject setEmail:[NSNumber numberWithBool:![[myObject email] boolValue]]]; 
NSError *error;     
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error in saving BriefCase object - error:%@" ,error);       
} 
NSLog(@"value is %d", [[myObject email] boolValue]); //value is 0 now
```

Here, I check the MOC I was sent and i see all values are 1. So when merge happens, no updates made. Where is the disconnect if I saw the object had a 0 after saving?

```
// Called when a ManagedObjectContext performs save operation
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSManagedObjectContext *receivedMOC = [notification object];
    NSArray *items = [MyObjectClass getAllMyObjectsInManagedObjectContext:receivedMOC];
for (int i=0; i < [items count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"value is %d", [[[items objectAtIndex:i] email] boolValue]);
}
```

add'l context creation code, may be the issue

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)temporaryContext {

NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator];
[newContext setUndoManager:nil];
[newContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
return newContext;
```

Comment: 1) I cannot see the actual merge in your code. - 2) Where does myObject come from?

Comment: thanks so mcuh for response! yea, sorry i have the merge after this, but what i was confised about was that the context received from the notification didnt have the changes. the merge is working fine, but its not merging the changes cause the context doesnt have them.

Comment: Where is myObject created?

Comment: hi, sorry, missed this part, myObject is passed into the method. Maybe that's the issue because its associated with another context? ill look into it

Comment: Which context is myObject associated with? The background MOC, the main MOC or a third one?

Comment: so myObject is created from an array using objectAtIndex. That array is created by calling a method that queries CD with a fetch request. That fetch request uses the same temporaryContext method. But i'm thinking, that method creates a new MOC. So i use that method to create this object, pass it to update method, but in update method (first code above) i call temporaryContext again which creates a new instance. so maybe i have 2 instances and thats the issue? does that make sense? ive pasted the temporaryContext code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `temporaryContext` creates a new MOC on each call, so is seems that you actually work with 2 different background MOCs. `myModel` is created on a MOC that is different from

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[MyAppDelegate application] temporaryContext];
```

and therefore saving the latter has no effect on the changes in `myModel`.

You have to modify your code such that only one temporary context is created and passed around.

Comment: thanks again, just wanted to follow up and say its working now! But i'm seeing some locks every now and then. When I look at the method called before the lock, its something that accesses the main MOC. Nothing in my refresh process accesses this, everything accesses a background MOC. BUT, I was thinking that the changes i make to the background MOC do get merged to the main MOC using the didSave notification. If I try to query one MOC while its doing mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification, would that be the issue? Or is it built to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you calling

```
[mainMOC mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
```

when handling the notification. This might explain what is happening. This should be called on the main thread.

Comment: I think mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification has to be called on the main context.

Comment: @MartinR: thanks, that was what I meant; but I tried to customize too much the answer without thinking too much...

Comment: thanks so mcuh for response sergio, sorry for all the questions! i have the merge after this, but what i was confised about was that the context received from the notification didnt have the changes. the merge is working fine, but its not merging the changes cause the context doesnt have them.

Comment: although you bring up a good point about the thread, does the merge call inherently always happen on main? because i am updating that stuff in background, leaving main thread for UI. since the notifications post on the thread thyre called from, would this merge then be on a background thread and be an issue? would that explain why context it receives doesnt have changes? thats whats confusing me most

Comment: well, it is pretty strange that your local context does not contain the new objects. I have never thought of "dumping" the context in the notification handler, so do not know if that is ok or not. about the thread: the notification is handled in the same thread where it is posted. you can wrap the merge call in `performSelectorOnMainThread:` and see whether this fixes it all. otherwise I would suggest in the first place to "dump" your local context just after the save and see if there everything is ok.

Comment: re: dumping the context...i was just thinking about debugging and how to check if context had updates pre merge. up above, i have the line showing the value post save and then pre merge its different so im wondering in between it gets lost.         here's my merge call if you wanna see, but it appears the issue is pre-merge. thanks!                if (managedObjectContext1 != self.managedObjectContext) {
  [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
 }

Comment: the only hypothesis I can do is that `myObject` does not belong to your temporary context... I also fear that `performSelectorInBackground` will spawn each time a new thread -- not sure if that is ok... you would probably want either create a new temporary context each time, or manage your background processing through GCD...

Comment: i updated post and answered martin above, you both may be on to issue. let me know what you think. i think youre right in that its not associated

Comment: thanks again, just wanted to follow up and say its working now! But i'm seeing some locks every now and then. When I look at the method called before the lock, its something that accesses the main MOC. Nothing in my refresh process accesses this, everything accesses a background MOC. BUT, I was thinking that the changes i make to the background MOC do get merged to the main MOC using the didSave notification. If I try to query one MOC while its doing mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification, would that be the issue? Or is it built to handle that?